# onmouseover and onmouseout

Tags: javascript, php, onmouseover, onmouseout

i have a problem with onmouseover and onnmouseout, it doesn't work.

```
$tr_mouseover = "#d3d3d3";
$tr_mouseout = "#bababa";

$table_height = "<tr bgcolor=".$tr_bg." height=\"40\" onmouseover=\"this.bgColor=".$tr_mouseover."\" onmouseout=\"this.bgColor=".$tr_mouseout."\"> ";
```

Comment: The bgcolor attribute is deprecated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried quoting your color values?  Like this:

```
$table_height = "<tr bgcolor=".$tr_bg." height=\"40\" onmouseover=\"this.bgColor='".$tr_mouseover."'\" onmouseout=\"this.bgColor='".$tr_mouseout."'\"> ";
```

Note the `'` characters that have been added around the color values.  The markup that gets generated should look roughly like this:

```
<tr bgcolor="#FF0000" height="40" onmouseover="this.bgColor='#d3d3d3';" onmouseout="this.bgColor='#bababa';">
```

...which behaves correctly for me in Chrome, Firefox, and IE.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.style.backgroundColor (to my knowledge there's no bgColor)

Comment: still doesn't work ... $table_height = "<tr bgcolor=".$tr_bg." height=70 onmouseover=\"this.style.backgroundColor=".$tr_mouseover."\" onmouseout=\"this.style.backgroundColor=".$tr_mouseout."\">";